# Error SqlExceptionHelper : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, tomcat9

I am getting error while I am calling an API to the server.
Here are the logs :

```
2022-04-29 12:25:36.013  WARN 25587 --- [-nio-443-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: S1000
2022-04-29 12:25:36.015 ERROR 25587 --- [-nio-443-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Java heap space
2022-04-29 12:25:36.093  WARN 25587 --- [l-1 housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Thread starvation or clock leap detected (housekeeper delta=50s527ms107µs731ns).
Exception in thread "javamelody mb-rule-engine" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at net.bull.javamelody.internal.model.Collector.collectLocalContextWithoutErrors(Collector.java:321)
        at net.bull.javamelody.FilterContext$CollectTimerTask.run(FilterContext.java:82)
        at java.base/java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:556)
        at java.base/java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:506)
29-Apr-2022 12:25:36.042 SEVERE [Catalina-utility-2] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.threadStart Exception processing background thread
        java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.threadStart(ContainerBase.java:1276)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessorMonitor.run(ContainerBase.java:1322)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
                at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
        Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
2022-04-29 12:25:36.244  WARN 25587 --- [-nio-443-exec-6] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: S1000
2022-04-29 12:25:36.245 ERROR 25587 --- [-nio-443-exec-6] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Can not read response from server. Expected to read 181 bytes, read 31 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
2022-04-29 12:25:36.308 ERROR 25587 --- [-nio-443-exec-2] o.s.b.w.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter  : Forwarding to error page from request [/v2/recommendation/get-recommended-institute] due to exception [could not extract ResultSet; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet]

org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not extract ResultSet; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:331) ~[spring-orm-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:233) ~[spring-orm-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:551) ~[spring-orm-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
        at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61) ~[spring-tx-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
```

Attaching screenshots :
[Java memory usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqzhL.png)
[System CPU usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rhkzl.png)

I also need to know what is the meaning of the line :

- HikariPool-1 - Thread starvation or clock leap detected (housekeeper delta=50s527ms107µs731ns).

***Could someone please help me out on this and explain what is this error?***

Comment: Explanation: your application uses more memory than you provide for it, what else do you need?

Comment: Thankyou for your EXPLAINATION. But isn't it unusual that a single service taking this much memory. Please follow the screenshot link : https://ibb.co/V3xTjyY And this happens suddenly.

Comment: You don't even give us a hint what "this much memory" is, so with the information you give, nothing is unusual. Also, each application has its own memory requirements, so even if you gave us your memory configuration, we couldn't say. Your application might have a memory leak - also nothing that can easily be handled here. And of course, OOME happens suddenly: Up until then, the process had enough memory. And it's rather random when it happens - might be that there's nothing wrong with your JDBC code - it probably just runs when some other component has long used up the lot of the memory

Comment: I got your point thankyou for the info :)

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` is that your application has used up all available heap memory.

The meaning of `Thread starvation or clock leap detected (housekeeper delta=50s527ms107µs731ns)` is that *something* is consuming all CPU and the (presumably) high priority housekeeper thread is noticing that it is being starved.

The starvation message is quite likely a consequence of the heap filling up.  When the heap is *nearly* full, the JVM can become non-responsive due to the GC *continually* running in a vain attempt to free up some space.  There is a JVM option that avoids this behavior ... by throwing the OOME when the GC is consuming too large a proportion of the available CPU.

Comment: Thankyou @Stephen that was very helpful. That _something_ you mentioned is most probably the class responsible for OOME. Please follow memory consumption screenshot of that class just before the OOME error : https://ibb.co/V3xTjyY . And I got this same error twice on two different days over two different classes of same application.  **One more piece of information is that two application(frontend and backend each) are deployed on same GCP server and sharing same tomcat.**

Comment: I don't think so.  To get the thread starvation behavior you need a situation where something is able to look out all other threads ... including high priority threads ... for long periods of time.  IMO, the most likely candidate is stop-the-world garbage collections; e.g. the "full collections" that get forced when the JVM is desperately trying to reclaim memory.

Comment: It is also possible that you *also* have a problem at the OS or hypervisor level caused by overcommitting RAM.  That can lead to *thrashing*.  There are too many *potential* problems to solve this by speculating.  You need to start by looking for what is causing the OOMEs.  Read about how to find Java memory leaks, etc.

Comment: Thanks man! I am able to found the issue. It should be resolved. I will monitor system for few more days.